# Interpreting Phillips Perron Test results using R

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, interpretation, unit-root

I performed `pptest` in R for corn variables and am unsure how to decipher the p-value and what that means for the hypothesis.

Comment: Can you the the output?

Answer (score 1):

The null is that of a unit root and the test has power against stationary alternatives. So if your p-value is "large", the test provides no evidence against the null of nonstationarity, while a small p-value does provide evidence in favor of the alternative of stationarity.